# Storing a list of different generic types in a class

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, dynamic

[image: Class structure]

I've attached a picture of what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have a list of T in a class

```
public class MyClass<T> 
    where T : IMyInterface
{
    public List<T> list = new List<T>;
}
```

Now, another class has a list of MyClass.

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public List<MyClass<IMyInterface>> list = new List<MyClass<IMyInterface>>;
}
```

What is the T that I should put for MyClass? If I put T, then it assumes all types in that class are the same, but it isn't. If I put IMyInterface, I couldn't cast IMyInterface to T when accessing these classes.

```
new AnotherClass().list.Add(new MyClass<T>());
```

What is the type here right now? The list in AnotherClass generic type is IMyInterface but the thing I want to add in is T, which T I want to be dynamic but they are still under IMyInterface.

Comment: The problem is you're describing a solution to a problem, and not the actual problem.  What are you trying to solve??? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).

Comment: I haven't been working with c# for a while now, but I would not use generics. If you know you are putting only objects implementing your interface in it, why don't you use polymorphy. That means:
public List<IMyInterface> list=new List<IMyInterface>;

Comment: you seem to be confusing things. generics are not dynamically typed. everything in C# is statically typed except statements/declarations that involve the `dynamic` keyword, but that has nothing to do with generics. a `List<int>` is a list containing ONLY `int`s. `a List<IMyInterface>` is a list containing ONLY objects implementing `IMyInterface`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `T` in a generic must be the same through out its lifetime.

for an example

```
var a = new MyClass<int>();
a.list.Add(1); //since a's generic T is declared as int the list is now also int

var b = new MyClass<string>()
b.list.Add("string"); //in b its now declared as a string and avccepts only string
```

So when you are doing this.

```
var c = new MyClass<IMyInterface>();
c.list.Add(ObjectImplementingIMyInterface); //You must add something that implements IMyInterface
```

The only thing you know about the content is that it implements `IMyInterface` now if you want to split the execution of the object then you must check the type of the object via reflection.

```
if(c.list[i].GetType() == typeof(ClassA_IMyInterface)
{
    //Execute on ClassA_IMyInterface
    //If you are after the ClassA 
    //and want to run something speciffic for it the cast
    ClassA clA = = (ClassA)c.list[i];
    //Now you have access to the implementation of ClassA instead of just the interface 
}
else if (c.list[i].GetType() == typeof(ClassB_IMyInterface)
{
    //Execute on ClassB_IMyInterface
}
```

Here is an example i made in ConsoleApplication showing how it lays out.

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : IMyInterface
{
    public List<T> list = new List<T>();
}
public interface IMyInterface
{
}
public class Foo : IMyInterface
{
}
public class Bar : IMyInterface
{
}
public class FooBar
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var content = new MyClass<IMyInterface>();
        content.list.Add(new Foo());
        if (content.list[0] is Foo)
        {
            //Execute on Foo 
            var g = (Foo)content.list[0];
            //Now you can access Foo's methods and not only the Interfaces
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
        }
        else if (content.list[0] is Bar)
        {
            //Execute on Bar
            var g = (Bar)content.list[0];
            //Now you can access Bar's methods and not only the Interfaces
            Console.WriteLine("Bar");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `c.list[0] is dd1`.  This allows subclasses of dd1 to be treated with the code for dd1.

Comment: @Taemyr `is` is a bool evaluator (and i could probably use it instead of `GetType/typeof`. Are you thinking of `as` (close to casting, but allows for the result to be `null`)

Comment: I mean instead of GetType().  In your example using as would not make sense.

Comment: yes using `is` like that, would make it a little nicer as it is a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 6):

I think your issue is that you do not need to use generics for this. If you specify your class as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IList<IMyInterface> list = new List<IMyImterface>();
}
```

Then you can add to this any instance of any class implementing the interface.

```
public class DummyClass : IMyInterface {}

public class AnotherClass {
{
    IList<MyClass> anotherList = new List<MyClass>();

    public void AMethod()
    {
        MyClass myList = new MyClass();
        myList.Add(new DummyClass());

        anotherList.Add(myList);
    }
}
```

Then you can access all items from the list as IMyInterface directly, or if you want items of a specific class, you can use LINQ:

```
foreach (IMyImterface item in myList.Where(x => x is DummyClass))
{
    DummyClass dummy = (DummyClass)item;
}

// or
foreach (IMyImterface item in myList.OfType<DummyClass>())
{
    DummyClass dummy = (DummyClass)item;
}
```

Or you can just try casting and check if null:

```
foreach (IMyIntetface item in myList)
{
    DummyClass dummy = item as DummyClass;
    if (dummy != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: the canonical way of getting all instances of a specific subtype from a sequence is `seq.OfType<T>()` (your version does two type checks). although you shouldn't be downcasting stuff in 99 out of 100 cases anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I expect that would be faster?

Comment: well I would assume the time-complexity is the same, but I wouldn't really worry about the performance, both are fast enough to never ever be the bottle-neck in your app. it's just cleaner to say what you want, rather than saying what something should do, knowing it will result in what you want. it's kind of a declarative vs imperative thing.

Comment: @SteveHarris I think the cast `(DummyClass)item` will throw an exception rather than return null. It should be `item as DummyClass`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean that you want to have multiple generic types in one list eg:

```
var ac = new AnotherClass();
ac.list.Add(new MyClass<int>()); 
ac.list.Add(new MyClass<bool>()); 
ac.list.Add(new MyClass<double>());
```

A simple way to do this is to define your list as a list of object:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public List<object> list = new List<object>();
}
```

The issue here is you could anything you like to that list, not just your generic class.  The following would also  be possible:

```
list.Add(1); 
list.Add("hello");
```

The only way you could restrict what you can add is to use an abstract base class.

```
public class MyClassBase 
{

}
public class MyClass<T> : MyClassBase
    where T : IMyInterface
{
    public List<T> list = new List<T>();
}
```

And then have a list of those:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public List<MyClassBase> list = new List<MyClassBase>();
}
```

You'll still have to do some type checking when accessing those objects but at least you'll know that the objects are restricted to those inheriting MyClassBase

Answer (score 3):

Using [covariant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/)?

```
public interface IMyInterface { }
public class A : IMyInterface { }
public class B : IMyInterface { }

// Covariant interface
public interface IMyClass<out T> { }

// Inherit IMyClass
public class MyClass<T> : IMyClass<T> where T : IMyInterface 
{ 
    public List<T> list = new List<T>(); 
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    // Note the list using IMyClass instead of the concrete MyClass type
    // The covariant interface type would allow any IMyInterface conversion
    public List<IMyClass<IMyInterface>> list = new List<IMyClass<IMyInterface>>();

    public AnotherClass()
    {
        this.list.Add(new MyClass<A>());
        this.list.Add(new MyClass<B>());
    }
}
```